# Discord Python Bot not sending DMS

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a discord bot in python try to send dms to every person in the server but it isnt working

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def mass(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await ctx.message.delete()

    for member in guild.members:
        try:
            await member.send("test")
            print(f"dmed {member.name}")
        except:
            pass
```

Im using latest discord.py version

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: I enabled them thanks for telling me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to enable intents

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True # Privileged intent

client = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also remember to enable privileged member intent in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)